# How can I set custom variables in tmux?

Tags: configuration, tmux, variable

I have the following section in my `tmux.conf` file:

```
bind -r H resize-pane -L 10 # defaults to Ctrl-LeftArrow
bind -r J resize-pane -D 10
bind -r K resize-pane -U 10
bind -r L resize-pane -R 10
```

Id like to set a custom variable called `step` and assign it to `10` so I can reference it as:

```
bind -r H resize-pane -L $step
```

I don't know how to do that in tmux configuration file, but I think it should be possible.

Answer (score 10):

Place this line in your config:

```
TMUX_STEP=10
```

And use it as such:

```
bind -r H resize-pane -L $TMUX_STEP
```

Comment: Does it have to start with `TMUX_` prefix?

Comment: @Chinggis6, no it does not.

Comment: Does it have to be in ALL_CAPS?

Comment: No, it does not. Like standard bash variables.

Comment: Unless I'm completely missing it, this seems to be completely undocumented in the man page... :|

Comment: @Droj this is a strength of tmux: the `bind-key` command can run a simple shell command. Like all shell commands, this value (TMUX_STEP) can be taken from the environment variables when it is invoked.

I'm not sure whether you can change this value (TMUX_STEP) in the current shell in tmux, or if it has to be from the session-creating shell, but the principle is the same.